# Load generated by distributed worker processes is not equivalent generated by single process

Tags: locust

I start another test trying to figure how users are allocated to worker node.

Here is my locust file.

```
@task
def mytask(self):
    self.client.get("/")


class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 2)
    tasks = [mytask]
```

It is nothing but access a Chinese search engine website that never failed to visit.

When I start 30 users running in single node, and RPS is 20.

```
locust -f try_baidu.py
```

[image]

and got running status and result as below.

[image]

I switch to distributed running mode using command in 3 terminal of my computer.

```
locust -f try_baidu.py --master #for master node
locust -f try_baidu.py --worker --master-host=127.0.0.1 #for worker node each
```

and I input same amount of users and hatch rate in locust UI as above, say 30 users and hatch rate 10.

I've got same RPS which is 20 or around, and each worker node runs 15 users.

This explains that number of user input in UI is total amount to simulated and dispersed around worker node. It is something like load balance to burden load generation.

But I don't know why same amount of users gives 2 different RPS when running in single node (Scenario 1) and distributed (Scenario 2). They shall be result into same or closed RPS as above test.

The only difference I can tell is above comparison is in same computer while Scenario 2 have worker nodes in 2 remote linux VMs. But is it real reason?

---

Question may be asked not very clearly and I add some testing result here trying to depict what I have when running distributed and in single node with specified users.

- Scenario 1: Single Node

[image: CPU utilization is about 50%]

- Scenario 2: Trying to simulate 3 worker process each of which running 30 users but get lower RPS even.

[image: CPU utilization is about 30%]

from console I can see that each worker process starts 30 users as expected but have no idea why  RPS is only 1/3 or single node.

- Scenario 3: Adding triple times users to 90 for each worker process and get almost same RPS as running in single node.

[image: CPU utilization is about 50%]

It seems Scenario 3 is what I expected for triple simulation amount. But why locust graphic panel gives each worker process is running 90 users?

- Scenario 4: To make sure locust truly distribute users specified to each worker node, I put 30 users for single worker node and get the same RPS as single node (not distributed)

[image: CPU utilization is about 50%]

Do I have to adding up total users distributed to worker node and input this total amount?

Comment: Can you give some more info on how your test? Note that the number of users is total, not per worker process. Also, see the first question in https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Can you add your test plan? There appears to be an issue somewhere, maybe it has to do with that. ”each worker process is running 90 users” Your interpretation is not correct - Locust displays the *total* user count (for *all* worker processes) but this still doesnt explain some of the issues youre having..

Comment: Hi, @Cyberwiz, thanks for your patience. I add another new simple test trying to make you understand my question since I am quite new to Locust.

Comment: Are your response times different between the runs? If the distributes runs have higher response times (for whatever reason) then that would explain why they deliver less RPS per user

Comment: Hi, I guess the sort of root cause is found. I shift the master node to another VM and it works fine that all requests from all worker nodes are collected to correct RPS result. It is weird original master node seems to miss requests sent by one of worker node and present half of expected RPS. I would like to figure  out what makes this happened in terms of system configuration of original master node later, but showstopper is temporarily removed.

Comment: Huh. What a strange problem. But I guess it explains it. If the problem stays solved or you figure out the root cause then consider editing your original question (to emphasize the symptoms that were actually pertinent) and answering it yourself, if you think it would be useful for somebody else.

Comment: Would it be possible for locust to allow calculating requests per second using raw data like JMeter? I could so far download data from  web UI as csv file which contains only summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved to some extend by set master node to another system. I guess there should be something interferes master to collect requests sent from one of workers which results into half of expected RPS. This may suggest a possible solution to lower RPS than it should be.